# Map-reduce comparing latest and earliest values

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a schema similar to:

```
{
  id: 1,
  pid: 1,
  batch: 1,
  count: 2,
}

{
  id: 2,
  pid: 1,
  batch: 2,
  count: 4,
}

{
  id: 3,
  pid: 1,
  batch: 3,
  count: 6,
}
```

And I want to write a map-reduce function to return the incremental difference between the count for the most recent batch, and the earliest batch.

With the data above, this would return something like:

```
pid: 1, diff: 4
```

Any ideas on how to go about this?  I'm using Mongo, but if there's a Java/Hadoop example that works i'll happily take it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in lines of the following algorithm:

**Map**

Input: K1 = "file offset", V1 = Jason Object

Output: K2 = "pid : 1", V2 = "count: 2"

**Reduce**

Input: K2 = "pid: 1", list of V2 ("count : 2, count : 4, count : 6")

Output: K3 = "pid: 1", V3 : "(Max of V2 minus Min of V2)"

It is assumed in the schema that the count is always incremental for the given series of batches. In case if it is not, then you can add "batch" to the value.

V2="batch : 1, count:2".

V3 = "Count of Max batch minus Count of Min batch"